# Python modules for visualization of C++ code

Tags: c++, python, grep, data-visualization

I'm looking for python modules that can help with grepping C++ code.  I have a large code base that I would like to do some analysis on.  Ultimately I would like to come up with a graphical map of the software.  There is lots of message passing going on amongst apps so I would like to be able to capture that information and present it visually.  I have been looking around at some of the data visualization packages but have only stumbled on math and plotting related ones.

What are the best tools for this job, preferably in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best tool for the job is Graphviz. If you look at their [gallery](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php) you'll find the sort of thing that you're interested in along with links to projects.

Under the language bindings section [here](http://www.graphviz.org/Resources.php) there are a few python entries. Personally I don't use them as the dot language format is simple enough that you can build up fairly complex graphs from Python just using print statements.

Answer (score 1):

You ca look at [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org/) and see if it does (at least some part of) what you want. It generates call graph and class diagrams directly in html or xml format (I believe you need to have [dot](http://www.graphviz.org/) installed for fancy graphs).